# How to zoom-in/out to an OpenGL screen without rendering the entire screen again

Tags: c++, opengl

I am writing a program to display 5 millions rectangles, rendering with OpenGL.
It takes about approx. 3 seconds to display these rectangles on the screen.
However, it will also take the same time when I try to zoom in/out or pan left/right the screen.

I am wondering if there is a way to save everything into memory/buffer, therefore the screen doesn't have to be redraw all over again and again.

I am also open with other solutions.

The following is my reshape function:

```
static void reshape_cb() {
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLint) screen_width, (GLint) screen_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D (0.0, DESIGN_SIZE, 0.0, DESIGN_SIZE);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am writing a program to display 5 millions rectangles, rendering with OpenGL. It takes about approx. 3 seconds to display these rectangles on the screen.

This sounds like you're sending drawing commands in a very inefficient manner. Modern GPUs are capable of rendering hundreds of millions of triangles per second. My guess would be, that you're using immediate mode.

> I am wondering if there is a way to save everything into memory/buffer, therefore the screen doesn't have to be redraw all over again and again.

Zooming usually means a change of point of view or rendering resolution, hence it will require a full redraw.

> I am also open with other solutions. Thank you.

You should optimize your drawing code. The keywords are:

- Vertex Arrays
- Vertex Buffer Objects
- large drawing batches

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am actually reading the coords. of each rectangle from a database and draw it with GL_LINE_LOOP. Do you think that is the issue?

Comment: @user3097451: You mean you're reading it from the database when rendering? Well, yes, that surely is the issue. You should read the geometry data only if it changes and upload it into OpenGL server side (=GPU) memory in the form of a Vertex Buffer Object.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that drawing this scene shouldn't take 3 seconds.

However, to answer the question: Yes, you can do that.

You'd render to an offscreen framebuffer (FBO), which you could even do on another thread with a separate shared context so it doesn't block the GUI. Then, the GUI would draw using the most recently rendered FBO (you'd double-buffer these so another one could be drawing while you use the old one for display). You could then pan and zoom around on the rendered FBO at full interactive framerate. Of course you couldn't pan further up/down/left/right than you rendered, and if you zoom in too much (more than 1.5x or 2x) things will get blurry. But it can be done. Also, as noted in the other answer, your view point or geometry or shading can't change, it will be just like moving around in a fixed photo.